# Dataflow job stucks while reading 35,000th file from google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

```
class Mp3_to_npyFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        filename, e = element

        # get mp3 from the storage
        bucket = storage.Client().get_bucket('BUCKET_NAME')
        blob = bucket.get_blob(filename)
        tmp_mp3 = TemporaryFile()
        blob.download_to_file(tmp_mp3)
        tmp_mp3.seek(0) 

        array = do_something(tmp_mp3)
        write_numpy_array(array)
        return something

def run():
    pp = beam.Pipeline(RUNNER,options=opts)
    l = (pp
         | 'Read TSV' >> ReadFromText(INPUT_TSV, skip_header_lines=1) 
         | 'Parse TSV' >> beam.Map(parseTSV) 
         | 'MP3 to npy' >> beam.ParDo(Mp3_to_npyFn())
        )
    job = pp.run()
    job.wait_until_finish()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 744, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 423, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "main2_mod.py", line 57, in process
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 227, in get_bucket
    bucket.reload(client=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_helpers.py", line 130, in reload
    _target_object=self,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 293, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500 GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my_db?projection=noAcl: Backend Error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 649, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 176, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 38, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 39, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 44, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 54, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 246, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 142, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 560, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 561, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 740, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 746, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 785, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 744, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 422, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 870, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 142, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 560, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 561, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 740, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 746, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 800, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/future/utils/__init__.py", line 421, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 744, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 423, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "main2_mod.py", line 57, in process
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 227, in get_bucket
    bucket.reload(client=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_helpers.py", line 130, in reload
    _target_object=self,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 293, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500 GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/cochlear_db?projection=noAcl: Backend Error [while running 'MP3 to npy']
```

The tsv file contains a list of 0.4M filenames(.mp3). After parsing, it reads each mp3 files and does some processes. When I tested with a list of 5 files in tsv, it worked OK. But testing with 0.4M files, it stucks at 
 reading 35,000th file with Error 500. It seems to retry many times and finally fails.

FYI, mp3 files are located in "gs://bucket_name/same_subdir/id_string.mp3", where the ids are ordered like 100001,100002,100003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by explicitly providing authentication credentials in the pipeline. In my guess, the workers lose permission while retrying after fail.

```
# get mp3 from the storage
    credentials = compute_engine.Credentials()
    project = <PROJECT_NAME>

    client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project)
    bucket = client.get_bucket(<BUCKET_NAME>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use [GcsIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.2.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio.html) instead of the storage client.
Please retrying your calls and for retriable errors use exponential [backoff](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/exponential-backoff).

Comment: Thanks for advice! I resolved the issue (see my answer). I will also try with your answer too!!

Comment: I tried this but in this case I had problem in auto-scaling. For now, my answer worked well.